# Visual Studio web test transaction total request time wrong

Tags: visual-studio, webtest

I have a very quick question. I have recorded web scenarios and created different transactions on top of those recorded web requests as well as load tests on it.

When I run the load test and wanted to see the detail of each run, I figured the transaction total time does not match the total of each request under it.

Do you have any idea why?

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question as defined in the [help] pages. Have you considered think times? The question needs more details.

Comment: No think time. There are dependent requests which are not visible, and I can not see those details,

Comment: I think you have given the answer in your comment. You could try running the test with follow dependent requests turned off (have forgotten the correct name of the property) and see what happens, as a check.

Comment: The 21 second time you have circled includes think time in between the requests. If you recorded the test, these think times are placed on the request automatically and you might not see them. But they are in the properties of each request.